What is the cardinality of the set of total functions from $ℕ$ to $ℕ$ that satifistifed $ \left| \{n\in\mathbb{N}:f(n)\neq n \} \right|<\aleph_0$?
The question :
Let $S$ to be the set of total functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ that applies:
$$ \left| \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n) \neq n \} \right| < \aleph_0 $$
I know that there is a similar question - Proving the set of functions from $N \longrightarrow N$, when $f(n) \neq n$ for every $n \in N$ is uncountable but here we relate to the set of total functions only.
But I completely thought that the cardinality of the related set that applies these conditions is $\aleph$ because we can handle the set of total functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ as :
$$  \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n) = n \}  \cup S = \mathbb N ^\mathbb N $$
Hence, $S$ is not countable.
What I'm missing here? I consulted other students who are completely sure that $S$ is countable.

Your union does not include all elements of $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$.

Note that we can only choose the value of finite many $f(n)$ , for all $n$ but finite many we have $f(n)=n$ , so no choice.

@GEdgar give an example, I can't see it

Let's say an $n$ with $f(n) \ne n$ is a "moving point" for $f$.  So the set $S$ contains functions with finitely many moving points.  And ${ n \in \mathbb{N} : f(n) = n }$ contains the function with no moving points.  But there are still more functions: those with infinitely many moving points.

Your link deals with total functions as well.  Total just means that $f(n)$ has a value for all $n$.  It is the default when you write that something is a function from $N \to N$.  Your last only adds one function, the identity, to $S$ so there are many missing from $N^N$.  One simple example is $f(n)=n+1$

@RossMillikan I do understand your example but, $$ f(n+1) =n $$ is belongs to S in the same way

No, $f(n)=n+1$ has $f(n) \neq n$ for all $n$, so its cardinality is $\aleph_0$.  It does not belong to $S$.  Your function is not one because you have not defined it for the minimum of your naturals, be it $0$ or $1$.

The set $S$ simply is $\{f\in\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\;:\;\{n\in\mathbb N \;:\;f(n)\neq n\}\text{ is finite}\}$. It is the union of the sets $S_n:=\{f\in\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\;:\;\forall k\geq n, f(k)=k\}$ which all are (at most) countable as $S_n$ is in bijection with $\mathbb N^{n}$ ($S_0$ only contains the identity of $\mathbb N$).
And your union makes no sense as the first set is included in $\mathbb N$ and not $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Furthermore, $f$ isn’t fixed in your problem.
